# Matplotlib axes autoscale does not work with after twinx()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have found that I can not get axes autoscale to work on the 1st axes after creating a second axes using twinx.  Is this expected?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)
y1 = 0.05 * x**2
y2 = -1 *y1

fig, axL = plt.subplots() # Make Left Axes
axR = axL.twinx() # Make Left Axes
axL.plot(x, y1, 'g-') # Plot on Left
axL.grid()
axL.autoscale(enable=True, axis=u'both', tight=False)
plt.show()
# Do some stuff then later plot on axR
```

When I run the above code it autoscales in the y-direction correctly on the left axes (0 to 5) but changes the X-Axis scale to +/- 0.06 instead of the correct 0 to 10.  However, once axR is no longer blank and something is plotted on axR it behaves as I would expect.

This is only an example as I first came across this issue in more complicated PyQT4 GUI that allows the user to create multiple subplots & left/right combinations.  Since the user is the one manually controlling the plot creation order it is possible for the above situation to present itself.

Is there a way for autoscale to work with a blank twinx right axes.  Or is the Xlimit just going to have to be manually set?

FYI, I am using Python 3.4 as part of Anaconda v2.0.1 with Matplotlib v1.3.1

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is merely a workaround than a proper solution or explanation.

Simply add an invisible point in the right axes so it is not completely empty:

```
axR.plot(0, 0, visible=False)
```

You have to make sure though, that the invisible point lies within the ranges of the data that you plot in `axL`. E.g.:

```
axR.plot(np.mean(x),np.mean(y1),visible=False)
```

---

As for an explanation (I'm guessing):

`axR.dataLim` is `[-np.inf, np.inf]` initially. The union of `axR.dataLim` and `axL.dataLim` still gives `[-np.inf, np.inf]` which is then collapsed to `[0,0]`.

---

**EDIT:** This was fixed recently ([here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/commit/26ed35b78cd7542f6841835925be53419661e36e)). Upgrading to matplotlib v1.4.* should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks! I tested this after upgrading matplotlib on my personal machine and it worked as expected.  Unfortunately at work everything is config controlled so I will have to see if I can convince them to do the same.